# Nhibernate Identity Skips a thousand

Tags: nhibernate

i have an application and the main object have an identity like always. in the database the ids are saved in order increased by 1 as expected 1,2,3,4,5,6 .... N... as expected

but when showed in the view the ids are different like 1 to 12 and then they jump a thousand to 1012

the weirdes is that when i debugg it and i do the Session.Query().ToList();

the ids's are bad, and they just came from the database, i haven't map them or anything.

and if i query by id the object is retrieved it correctly.

```
public class BaseModel {public virtual int Id { get: set; }}

public class WorkOrder: BaseModel {}
```

and my Mapping

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<id name="Id">
  <generator class="identity" />
</id>
```

the app is in production, and we have been creating/updating/deleting several work orders many times, and i had this problems before while developing, but it came back.

is it because the ids is inherited by a base model, or is it any kind of bug of Nhibernate?

Answer (score 0):

The identity generator means that the database will generate the ids. I suggest take a look at the column definition there.